# C# Accord.net. text classfication

Tags: c#, machine-learning, tf-idf, text-classification, accord.net

I have unknown number of columns in my TFIDF vector.
my clasificaton code is:

```
double[][] inputs = table.ToJagged<double>("ColumnName1","columnName2");
int[] outputs = table.Columns[2].ToArray<int>();
var teacher = new NaiveBayesLearning<NormalDistribution>();
var nb = teacher.Learn(inputs, outputs);
```

i don't know how to pass unknown no of columns for input.

Answer (score 0):

One option for handling a dynamic set of inputs would be to use an SVM with a `DynamicTimeWarping` Kernel. The documentation with example code is here:

http://accord-framework.net/docs/html/T_Accord_Statistics_Kernels_DynamicTimeWarping.htm